# Project module not found outside virtualenv

Tags: python, import, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

My project has basically an architecture like this:

```
src
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
└── core
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── module1.py
    └── module2.py
```

All `__init__.py` files are empty, in `main.py` I have a `from src.core.module1 import stuff` and I am running `main.py` from the `src` folder.
When I'm running it from my project virtual environment everything works fine, but outside of the virtual environment I have an `ImportError: no module named src.core.module1`. I cannot understand why, because this module is in the project, not related to the Python environment packages...

(Windows / Python 2.7.14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `from core.module1 import stuff`.  You should not import `src` since you are in that location with your main.py already.

Comment: Thanks it actually works, but I still do not understand why it works when I am in the virtual environment ?

Comment: @Marv Where is your virtual environment located.  If `src` is a sub-folder inside the virtual installation that would explain it.

Comment: No, the environment is in C:\Users\myusername\Envs\envname and the project is in C:\Sources\project

Comment: @Marv  No sorry I really don't have a clue what could be causing that.

Comment: Actually I might have an idea: I am using virtualenvwrapper and I gave to the `setprojectdir` command the path above src (because this is the root path of my project) but I think it is adding this path to the Python path and then allows it to find the src package...

Comment: @Marv   That makes sense, it would cause exactly that.